# Error: Class 'League\Flysystem\AwsS3v3\AwsS3Adapter' not found in file

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, amazon-s3, composer-php

laravel Framework is 7.9.2.

`composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 ~1.0` installed to use aws s3.

It runs on localhost, but when I put it on the aws server,

`Error: Class 'League\Flysystem\AwsS3v3\AwsS3Adapter' not found` error appears.

However, when I checked with composer licenses,

It is identified as league/flysystem v1.0.67 MIT.

composer license

```
Name: laravel/laravel
Version: dev-master
Licenses: MIT
Dependencies:

Name                                Version    License       
asm89/stack-cors                    1.3.0      MIT           
brick/math                          0.8.15     MIT           
dnoegel/php-xdg-base-dir            v0.1.1     MIT           
doctrine/inflector                  1.3.1      MIT           
doctrine/instantiator               1.3.0      MIT           
doctrine/lexer                      1.2.0      MIT           
dragonmantank/cron-expression       v2.3.0     MIT           
egulias/email-validator             2.1.17     MIT           
facade/flare-client-php             1.3.2      MIT           
facade/ignition                     2.0.2      MIT           
facade/ignition-contracts           1.0.0      MIT           
fideloper/proxy                     4.3.0      MIT           
filp/whoops                         2.7.1      MIT           
fruitcake/laravel-cors              v1.0.6     MIT           
fzaninotto/faker                    v1.9.1     MIT           
guzzlehttp/guzzle                   6.5.3      MIT           
guzzlehttp/promises                 v1.3.1     MIT           
guzzlehttp/psr7                     1.6.1      MIT           
hamcrest/hamcrest-php               v2.0.0     BSD           
laravel/framework                   v7.9.2     MIT           
laravel/tinker                      v2.4.0     MIT           
laravel/ui                          v2.0.3     MIT           
lcobucci/jwt                        3.3.1      BSD-3-Clause  
league/commonmark                   1.4.2      BSD-3-Clause  
league/flysystem                    1.0.67     MIT           
mockery/mockery                     1.3.1      BSD-3-Clause  
monolog/monolog                     2.0.2      MIT           
myclabs/deep-copy                   1.9.5      MIT           
namshi/jose                         7.2.3      MIT           
nesbot/carbon                       2.33.0     MIT           
nikic/php-parser                    v4.4.0     BSD-3-Clause  
nunomaduro/collision                v4.2.0     MIT           
opis/closure                        3.5.1      MIT           
phar-io/manifest                    1.0.3      BSD-3-Clause  
phar-io/version                     2.0.1      BSD-3-Clause  
phpdocumentor/reflection-common     2.1.0      MIT           
phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock   5.1.0      MIT           
phpdocumentor/type-resolver         1.1.0      MIT           
phpoption/phpoption                 1.7.3      Apache-2.0    
phpspec/prophecy                    v1.10.3    MIT           
phpunit/php-code-coverage           7.0.10     BSD-3-Clause  
phpunit/php-file-iterator           2.0.2      BSD-3-Clause  
phpunit/php-text-template           1.2.1      BSD-3-Clause  
phpunit/php-timer                   2.1.2      BSD-3-Clause  
phpunit/php-token-stream            3.1.1      BSD-3-Clause  
phpunit/phpunit                     8.5.4      BSD-3-Clause  
psr/container                       1.0.0      MIT           
psr/event-dispatcher                1.0.0      MIT           
psr/http-message                    1.0.1      MIT           
psr/log                             1.1.3      MIT           
psr/simple-cache                    1.0.1      MIT           
psy/psysh                           v0.10.3    MIT           
ralouphie/getallheaders             3.0.3      MIT           
ramsey/collection                   1.0.1      MIT           
ramsey/uuid                         4.0.1      MIT           
scrivo/highlight.php                v9.18.1.1  BSD-3-Clause  
sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup  1.0.1      BSD-3-Clause  
sebastian/comparator                3.0.2      BSD-3-Clause  
sebastian/diff                      3.0.2      BSD-3-Clause  
sebastian/environment               4.2.3      BSD-3-Clause  
sebastian/exporter                  3.1.2      BSD-3-Clause  
sebastian/global-state              3.0.0      BSD-3-Clause  
sebastian/object-enumerator         3.0.3      BSD-3-Clause  
sebastian/object-reflector          1.1.1      BSD-3-Clause  
sebastian/recursion-context         3.0.0      BSD-3-Clause  
sebastian/resource-operations       2.0.1      BSD-3-Clause  
sebastian/type                      1.1.3      BSD-3-Clause  
sebastian/version                   2.0.1      BSD-3-Clause  
swiftmailer/swiftmailer             v6.2.3     MIT           
symfony/console                     v5.0.8     MIT           
symfony/css-selector                v5.0.8     MIT           
symfony/error-handler               v5.0.8     MIT           
symfony/event-dispatcher            v5.0.8     MIT           
symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts  v2.0.1     MIT           
symfony/finder                      v5.0.8     MIT           
symfony/http-foundation             v5.0.8     MIT           
symfony/http-kernel                 v5.0.8     MIT           
symfony/mime                        v5.0.8     MIT           
symfony/polyfill-ctype              v1.15.0    MIT           
symfony/polyfill-iconv              v1.15.0    MIT           
symfony/polyfill-intl-idn           v1.15.0    MIT           
symfony/polyfill-mbstring           v1.15.0    MIT           
symfony/polyfill-php56              v1.15.0    MIT           
symfony/polyfill-php72              v1.15.0    MIT           
symfony/polyfill-php73              v1.15.0    MIT           
symfony/polyfill-util               v1.15.0    MIT           
symfony/process                     v5.0.8     MIT           
symfony/routing                     v5.0.8     MIT           
symfony/service-contracts           v2.0.1     MIT           
symfony/translation                 v5.0.8     MIT           
symfony/translation-contracts       v2.0.1     MIT           
symfony/var-dumper                  v5.0.8     MIT           
theseer/tokenizer                   1.1.3      BSD-3-Clause  
tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles   2.2.2      BSD-3-Clause  
tymon/jwt-auth                      1.0.0      MIT           
vlucas/phpdotenv                    v4.1.4     BSD-3-Clause  
voku/portable-ascii                 1.4.10     MIT           
webmozart/assert                    1.8.0      MIT
```

My github address is https://github.com/Tsuribarii/FishHook_Back

I don't know what the problem is. If you have any difficulties like me, please help me.

Comment: have you run `composer install` ?

Comment: @Christophe Hubert I tried composer install, composer update, but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you try as well `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: @Christophe Hubert  I've tried composer dump-autoload, but nothing has changed.

Comment: You shouldn't need to require any extra package to make it work - `Flysystem` is already by default included in Laravel7. Why did you installed `flysystem-aws-s3-v3` on your local machine?

Comment: @Christophe Hubert Before using the S3 driver, the corresponding package was installed through the composer. 
laravel.kr/docs/7.x/…
I tried composer remove league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3:~1.0, but it hasn't been erased.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @sadaiMudiNaadhar My GitHub address is https://github.com/Tsuribarii/FishHook_Back.
The address of the file upload is https://github.com/Tsuribarii/FishHook_Back/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/ImageController.php

Comment: @jekim, Have you imported that anywhere in repo? There will be trace.

Comment: Check-in storage/logs/laravel.log for getting the trace. So that we can help

Comment: What do you mean by "When I put it on the aws server"?

Answer (score 0):

composer remove league/flysystem

after

composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 ~1.0

composer license

Result:
league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3